# NativeScript and a separate NavigationBar (ActionBar) for each tab

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to implement a UI in my NativeScript app, where the app has 2 tabs, with each tab having a navigation stack of its own. A similar pattern is seen in some apps, such as the Photos app. Here is a demonstration:

[image]

Is that possible with NativeScript? With the following code (Angular 2), I end up with a single navigation bar shared across both tabs. Only the second one (title Nearby) is kept:

```
<TabView>
  <StackLayout *tabItem="{ title: 'Home' }">
    <ActionBar title="Home"></ActionBar>
    <mp-home></mp-home>
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout *tabItem="{ title: 'Nearby' }">
    <ActionBar title="Nearby"></ActionBar>
    <Label text="Placeholder for Nearby"></Label>
  </StackLayout>
</TabView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered by looking at the source code of `nativescript-angular` that there is a [`SelectedIndexValueAccessor`](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/master/nativescript-angular/value-accessors/selectedIndex-value-accessor.ts#L26) directive which adds support for `ngModel` to `TabView` components. It syncs the `ngModel` value to the `selectedIndex` for the tab, which means we can use the following code to update the `ActionBar` title property:

```
<TabView [(ngModel)]="selectedTabIndex">

  <ActionBar
   [title]="selectedTabIndex === 0 ? homeTab.title : nearbyTab.title">
  </ActionBar>

  <StackLayout *tabItem="homeTab">
    <mp-home></mp-home>
  </StackLayout>

  <StackLayout *tabItem="nearbyTab">
    <Label text="Placeholder for Nearby"></Label>
  </StackLayout>

</TabView>
```

That works, but it still means we only have a single `ActionBar` (iOS Navigation Bar). That's not ideal if you're trying to build a UI in which each tab has its own navigation stack, but from looking at the source code for the `TabView` component, it appears that it is how it works: every time a new `TabView` instance is created, [the constructor of `TabView` replaces the instance of the `actionBar` on the topmost `page` object with itself](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/master/nativescript-angular/directives/action-bar.ts#L56).

For my app I'm going to make sure that the tab bar is only visible on the topmost page, which avoids the above being a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to make it work with `SelectedIndexValueAccessor` directive, so i adapted another [solution](http://www.nativescriptsnacks.com/snippets/2016/08/02/get-active-tab-index.html), hope somebody finds it useful:

mainPage.html:

```
<ActionBar [title]="tabs[tabId].title" class="action-bar"></ActionBar>

<GridLayout>
    <TabView #tabview (selectedIndexChanged)="tabIndexChanged($event)">

      <StackLayout *tabItem="tabs[0]" >
          <first-tabview-item></first-tabview-item>
      </StackLayout>

      <StackLayout *tabItem="tabs[1]">
          <second-tabview-item></second-tabview-item>
      </StackLayout>

      <StackLayout *tabItem="tabs[2]">
          <third-tabview-item></third-tabview-item>
      </StackLayout>

    </TabView>
</GridLayout>
```

mainPage.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "main-page",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./mainPage.html",
    styleUrls: ["./mainPage-common.css", "./mainPage.css"],
})
export class MainPageComponent implements OnInit {
    private tabs: object[];
    private tabId: number;

    constructor() { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {

        this.tabs = [
            {
                title: 'Tab 1 title',
                iconSource: '~/images/tab1.png',
            },
            {
                title: 'Tab 2 title',
                iconSource: '~/images/tab2.png',
            },
            {
                title: 'Tab 3 title',
                iconSource: '~/images/tab3.png',
            },
        ];

    }

    public tabIndexChanged(event: any) {
        this.tabId = event.newIndex;
        console.log(`Selected tab index: ${event.newIndex}`);
    }
}
```